# Is it possible to increase the number of CPUs used by ABAQUS for (pre)processing BEFORE job submission?

Tags: parallel-processing, abaqus, finite-element-analysis

I have a script which involves running certain pre-processing operations on the input file, which is generated by the meshing software Trelis. Before I can submit the job where I can easily define the number of CPUs to be used for solving, is it also possible to increase the speed with which ABAQUS does the pre-processing by assigning more CPUs? I can't find any such option on the ABAQUS GUI.

Comment: Why the negative vote? What am I supposed to show if there is nothing available in the ABAQUS manuals about multi-threading before submitting a job? I asked to see if anyone else has previously considered this problem and, hopefully, solved it.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't. But you can look at the [submodel](https://info.simuleon.com/blog/using-submodeling-in-abaqus-to-focus-on-a-region-of-interest-in-a-larger-model) concept. Such an option focuses on the analysis of the region of interest.  It is of particurlarly interest when dealing with big models.

Comment: Thank you for your response. The problem is, that I perform some mesh editing in Abaqus on an imported mesh. But your commend reminds me that it would also be possible to perform this outside ABAQUS.
Thank you for answering.